# "Desktop" Folder moved, but can I switch it back?

Tags: windows-10, desktop, onedrive, desktop-customization

Presently, my desktop folder is: `c:\users\glenn\onedrive\desktop`. Meaning this stuff actually appears on my desktop.

I still have things in: `c:\users\glenn\desktop`.  but they do not appear on the desktop and I believe they used to.

I don't know when / why / how the switch happened, but I don't necessarily want every item I save to my desktop to be sync'ed to OneDrive.

Is this set by Windows 10 (Build 17763) or OneDrive? Can I switch it back? How it is configured?

Thank you for your wisdom.

Comment: Here is tutorial for changing the desktop folder: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/74971-move-location-desktop-folder-windows-10-a.html . If it doesn't work, it can be done also with registry edits. Can't say how this has happened though. Have you possibly accidently moved the desktop folder?

Comment: Thanks! I think OneDrive is the culprit, but I may have done it mistakenly. ???

Comment: You're welcome. Might be hard to find out the cause, but if it is the OneDrive, it is plausible that it'll happen again. Did you manage to change it back?

Comment: Yes. it worked.